# Index out of bounds when replacing NaNs through a function in Pandas

Tags: python, function, pandas, indexoutofboundsexception, nan

I have created a function that replaces the NaNs in a Pandas dataframe with the means of the respective columns.  I tested the function with a small dataframe and it worked.  When I applied it though to a much larger dataframe (30,000 rows, 9 columns) I got the error message: IndexError: index out of bounds

The function is the following:

```
# The 'update' function will replace all the NaNs in a dataframe with the mean of the respective columns

def update(df):   # the function takes one argument, the dataframe that will be updated
      ncol = df.shape[1]  # number of columns in the dataframe
      for i in range(0 , ncol):  # loops over all the columns
             df.iloc[:,i][df.isnull().iloc[:, i]]=df.mean()[i]  # subsets the df using the isnull() method, extracting the positions
                                                        # in each column where the 
      return(df)
```

The small dataframe I used to test the function is the following:

```
     0   1   2  3
0   NaN NaN  3  4
1   NaN NaN  7  8
2   9.0 10.0 11 12
```

Could you explain the error?  Your advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are getting "index out of bounds" is because you are assigning the value `df.mean()[i]` when `i` is one iteration of what are supposed to be ordinal positions.  `df.mean()` is a `Series` whose indices are the columns of `df`.  `df.mean()[something]` implies `something` better be a column name.  But they aren't and that's why you get your error.

***your code... fixed***

```
def update(df):   # the function takes one argument, the dataframe that will be updated
      ncol = df.shape[1]  # number of columns in the dataframe
      for i in range(0 , ncol):  # loops over all the columns
             df.iloc[:,i][df.isnull().iloc[:, i]]=df.mean().iloc[i]  # subsets the df using the isnull() method, extracting the positions
                                                        # in each column where the 
      return(df)
```

Also, your function is altering the `df` directly.  You may want to be careful.  I'm not sure that's what you intended.

---

All that said.  I'd recommend another approach

```
def update(df):
    return df.where(df.notnull(), df.mean(), axis=1)
```

---

You could use any number of methods to fill missing with the mean. I'd suggest using @MaxU's answer.

***`df.where`***
takes `df` when first arg is `True` otherwise second argument

```
df.where(df.notnull(), df.mean(), axis=1)
```

***`df.combine_first` with awkward `pandas` broadcasting***

```
df.combine_first(pd.DataFrame([df.mean()], df.index))
```

***`np.where`***

```
pd.DataFrame(
    np.where(
        df.notnull(), df.values,
        np.nanmean(df.values, 0, keepdims=1)),
    df.index, df.columns)
```

Comment: I changed the code in my function as you suggested but I still get an error :IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Comment: I ran that exact code with sample `df` and it ran.  I got `SettingWithCopyWarning` but it ran.

Comment: Yes I understand that.  In fact as I mentioned in my post the original function even before the correction run in the test dataframe.  However, it fails on the target dataframe which can be found here: https://ndownloader.figshare.com/files/2292172..  Can you explain this?

Answer (score 4):

I would use [DataFrame.fillna()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) method in conjunction with [DataFrame.mean()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) method:

```
In [130]: df.fillna(df.mean())
Out[130]:
     0     1   2   3
0  9.0  10.0   3   4
1  9.0  10.0   7   8
2  9.0  10.0  11  12
```

Mean values:

```
In [138]: df.mean()
Out[138]:
0     9.0
1    10.0
2     7.0
3     8.0
dtype: float64
```